# ¿Cómo sumar valores en un recorrido? PHP

Tags: php

Lo que intento hacer es que en cada uno de estos arrays muldimensionales, se sumen los valores que estan en la clave 0, pero no he podido dar con la respuesta

```html
<?php

array(2) { 
    [0]=> array(4) { ["camisa"]=> int(1) ["accesorio"]=> string(1) [0]=> int(70000) [1]=> string(2) "UT"} 
    [1]=> array(4) { ["camisa"]=> int(2) ["accesorio"]=> string(1) [0]=> int(60000) [1]=> string(2) "UW"} 
}

array(4) { 
    [0]=> array(4) { ["camisa"]=> int(1) ["accesorio"]=> string(1) [0]=> int(70000) [1]=> string(2) "UL"} 
    [1]=> array(4) { ["camisa"]=> int(2) ["accesorio"]=> string(1) [0]=> int(60000) [1]=> string(2) "UG"} 
    [2]=> array(4) { ["camisa"]=> int(5) ["accesorio"]=> string(1) [0]=> int(90000) [1]=> string(2) "UD"} 
    [3]=> array(4) { ["camisa"]=> int(7) ["accesorio"]=> string(1) [0]=> int(100000) [1]=> string(2) "UA"} 
}
//en la variable $caja hay más arrays, estos dos son solo uno de ellos


$array_almacenar=[];

for($i=0;$i<count($caja);$i++){
    for($p=0;$p<count($caja[$i]);$p++){
       $display='El total es:'.$caja[$i][$e][0];
      // $display=array_sum($caja[$i][$e][0]); Esto obvio no funciona, pero es un ejemplo
      //array_push($array_almacenar, $caja[$i][$e][0]); y este lo que hace es sumar los otros arrays exteriores y además me suma el de las camisas
      
      echo 'Usted tiene en total $'.$display.' del carrito <br>';
      //En el primer recorrido se supone que debe salir 130000, de sumar 70000 y 60000
      //En el segundo recorrido se supone que debe salir 320000, de sumar 70000, 60000, 90000 y 100000

    }
}
```

Hay alguna forma de hacer la suma sin que me tome la clave de camisa y solo me sume los valores de la clave 0?

Answer (score 0):

creo haber encontrado la solución a tu problema, he reescrito el código a mi gusto pero creo que lo podrás adaptar sin problemas. Lo principal es que entiendas la lógica del asunto.

```
<?php


$caja = array(
   array(
       array("camisa"=> 1,"accesorio"=>array(0=>70000, 1=>"UT"),),
       array( "camisa"=> 2,  "accesorio"=>array(0=>60000, 1=>"UW")),),
   array(
       array("camisa"=> 1,"accesorio"=>array(0=>70000, 1=>"UT"),),
       array( "camisa"=> 2,  "accesorio"=>array(0=>60000, 1=>"UW")),),
);

$suma=0;

for($i=0;$i<count($caja);$i++){
     for($x=0;$x<count($caja);$x++){
         $suma= $suma+$caja[$i][$x]["accesorio"][0];
    }
}

echo $suma;
?>
```

Este código sumara todas las posiciones 0 del array accesorios y las almacenara en $suma, pruébalo tu mismo y me dices.